# How can I insert svg code and not display the image until called?

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I would like to insert the SVG code at the bottom of my HTML code and not have the browser display it until i call it using a image tag or svg tag with a href and the id (i want the image in the middle of my nav bar).

what i am trying to get at is I want to have the svg file be able for me to change to color and keep my code "clean" so i don't have a huge block inside my nav bar.

i have been looking online and the only things i am running into is using the image tag (external file) witch wont let me change anything in the svg code(like change color when clicked on something). or inset it using the svg but i get a very ugly code. Am i dreaming?? or is this even possible?

thanks for your time!

Comment: set it to display:none when you insert it.

Comment: How you insert and called svg? With JS? Show your code.